# Eigenbasis of $4$x$4$ Circulant Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Given the $4$x$4$ circulant matrix

$A =   \begin{matrix}
        a & d & c & b \\
        b & a & d & c\\
        c & b & a & d\\
        d & c & b & a 
        \end{matrix}$

and the representation

$A = a*I_4 + b*C_4 + c*C_4^2 + d*C_4^3$

for $C_4 = \begin{matrix}
        0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
        1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
        0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
        0 & 0 & 1 & 0 
        \end{matrix}$

Find an eigenbasis for A. What are the eigenvalues in terms of $a,b,c,$ and $d$

The only notable thing I see is that the vector $v = [1 1 1 1]$  is an eigenvector of A with eigenvalue $a+b+c+d$. But that doesn't appear to be very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

The link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix#Eigenvectors_and_eigenvalues gives you your answer.

Comment: I had read through that before posting on here. It doesn't really help me in the way I need to formulate things. It doesn't say how to derive these eigenvectors and values from the polynomial form of A.

Comment: It shows how to get the eigenvectors/values for the first form of $A$.

Answer (score 1):

you can verify that the eigenvalue of $C_4$ are the four fourth roots of $1.$ suppose $\lambda$ is one of them, that is $\lambda^4 = 1$ and the corresponding eigenvector is $x=(1, \lambda, \lambda^2, \lambda^3)^\top.$ the eigenvalues of $A = a+bC+cC^2+ dC^3$ are $a+ b\lambda+c \lambda^2+d \lambda^3$ with the same eigenvector $x$ as before.

Comment: That does make sense. Does this mean that the eigenbasis of $M$ is identical to the eigenbasis of $C_4$, just with different corresponding eigenvalues?

Comment: @infinitylord, yes. the eigenbasis of $C_4$ is the eigenbasis of $A,$ a linear combination of the powers of $C_4.$